# Python: how to print only the lines that are true from csv file

Tags: python, csv, filter

As stated above. This is my csv file:

```
class, time, duration, building

math, 10:55, 2hr, B01

religion, 3:45, 2hr, B02

PDHPDE, 12:05, 2hr, B03

history, 1:00, 2hr, B04

history extension, 11:00, 2hr, B05
```

I expected the result to be just 1 line printed from this code that I used

```
import csv

with open('sched.csv') as csvfile:

    sched = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    for row in sched:
        a = row[1]
        print(a == '10:55')
```

However, my output was:

```
False

False

True

False

False
```

I just want to print out the 'true' line as "math, 10:55, 2hr, B01"

Comment: you want to use an if statment. right now you just say print the boolean result of the check for every line

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
import csv

with open('sched.csv') as csvfile:

    sched = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    for row in sched:
        a = row[1]
        if (a == '10:55'):
            print(row)
```

Instead of printing the result of (a == '10:55') which is either True or False for each row, you should check if it is True, then print the whole row.

Answer (score 0):

just add an if.

i think something like this would work

```
import csv

with open('sched.csv') as csvfile:

    sched = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    for row in sched:
        a = row[1]
        if a == '10:55':
            print(a == '10:55')
```